# How To Extend UIView Past Containing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a UINavigationController displayed as a child view controller taking up part of the screen. I've presented it using a simple embed segue, inside of the storyboard.

That UINavigationController's rootViewController has a small UIView which I'd like to extend past the bounds of the child view controller container.

My hierarchy looks like this:

```
1) Main View
 2) Container Nav Controller
    3) Root View Controller
      4) UIView which should extend past the bounds of 2
```

I've set clipsToBounds = false on all containing view, to no avail.

Doing a little bit of view debugging shows a `UINavigationTransitionView` between 2 and 3, with clipsToBounds = false. I'm pretty sure this is causing the issue (as an enterprise app, I don't mind using private APIs).

How can I allow the view to extend past all containers?

Comment: Share some code maybe? How do you present the UINavigationController?

Comment: It's presented using an embed segue in a container; everything's done via storyboard. I'll edit to clarify,

Answer (score 3):

In the ViewController that contains the `containerView`, under `viewDidLoad()`, add following code after creating the outlet for the `containerView`:

```
let layoutContainerView = self.containerView.subviews.first;
let navigationTransitionView = layoutContainerView?.subviews.first;
navigationTransitionView?.clipsToBounds = false;
```

This is kinda hacky, basically the first subview of the `navigationController`'s `view` is a `UINavigationTransitionView`, in which `clipsToBounds = true`.